# Is there a Pyrex baking dish that can fit a packaged dry lasagna noodle?

Tags: equipment, lasagna

Pyrex baking dishes all seem to be 9-inch by 13-inch, and many sites recommend that as the ideal size for lasagne.

As a result, the most tiresome and messy part of making lasagne is getting the standard sized 10-inch ready-to-cook dry noodles to fit into the 9-inch baking dish.

(I'll refrain from asking *why* "they" make things this way.)

Is there a 10.5" Pyrex baking dish available anywhere?

(I'm in Ontario Canada, but suspect this problem is not specific to here.)

Comment: Are you using pre-boiled or no-boil noodles? I find that pre-boiled noodles usually expand enough when boiling to fill a 13" pan the long way.

Comment: Likely a local problem, my lasagna noodles and my choice of pyrex dishes have very different sizes.

Comment: It's not just you, this is true here in the US too.  It's why I switched to fresh noodles, which are much easier to cut to size.

Comment: You need to add a country tag. Where I live (Europe) lasagne is not that big. Also I own a Pyrex dish which holds exactly two European lasagne sheets side by side, and the shop also sells a size for just one, for singles.

Answer (score 1):

There certainly are baking dishes that are sized to more easily fit lasagna noodles. Different brands & styles of noodles come in different sizes--so there is no one-size-fits-all baking dish.

The standard size Pyrex-brand glass baking dishes aren't specifically made for lasagna, and I'm not aware of them making a 10.5-inch size in that style (at least not in North America). I also find that the sweeping rounded corners, and sloping sides make the traditional Pyrex pan to be not great for lasagna--a personal opinion based on the fuss of trimming corners to fit, and each layer being wider/taller.

Pyrex does make [this stoneware pan](https://www.pyrexhome.com/product/modern-ash-stoneware-5-quart-baker) which is a 5-quart stoneware baking dish that measures 10.5x18.5 inches. It has the same rounded corners, but the sides are slightly straighter.

While it sometimes takes a bit of hunting to find a baking dish that is "just the right size," I've found that stoneware style baking dishes are often a bit more varied in size, and while you might not find a Big Name Brand pan in exactly the right size, I found a no-name stoneware pan with straight sides & sharper corners, which I find to be perfect for lasagna.

You might find hunting for stoneware pans in your preferred dimensions (and whatever other requirements are important to you!) will be easier to find the one that is right for you, rather than looking specifically for a Pyrex or glass pan.